# scroll com position:fixed perdendo a margem direita

Tags: jquery, html, layout-responsivo, layout

Quando eu desço a rolagem, a div#chat, fica fixa tudo certinho. Porem o problema e que o layout quebra perdendo a margem direita.
Como posso resolver esse problema?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

   var nav = $('#chat');

   $(window).scroll(function() {
     if ($(this).scrollTop() > 300) {

       nav.addClass("f-nav");
     } else {
       nav.removeClass("f-nav");
     }
   });

   
 });
```

```css
    .f-nav {
        z-index: 9999;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="width:100%; display:flex;">

  <div style="width:70%; height: 2000px; background-color: #ff9d58; margin:10px;">
  </div>


  <div id="chat" style="width:30%; height: 400px; background-color:#22792d; margin:10px;">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Faltou adicionar o CSS referente ao f-nav, não há nenhum position: fixed no código que postou.

Comment: Ola @GuilhermeNascimento ! realmente estava faltando. Agora ja atualizei o código obrigado por avisar.

Answer (score 1):

Sugiro fazeres isso com `float` e com percentagens. O problema que estás a ter é porque quando o elemento passa a `fixed` ele sai do bloco e passa a ocupar o seu espaço real.

Espaço real?

Sim, estás a dar `70%` a uma div e `30%` a outra, **mas também** `margin: 10px` a ambas. Ora isso é mais que `100%`, portanto quando a `div#chat` passa a `fixed` a outra toma o espaço real de `70% + 10px`. Baixando o `width` percentual já resolvia o problema: http://jsfiddle.net/LcfLy7za/1/

Surgiro também colocares o CSS todo à parte, e não inline no HTML pois é mais fácil de manter o código.

Fazendo tudo com percentagens:

```
body > div >div:first-child {
    float: left;
    width:68%;
    height: 2000px;
    background-color: #ff9d58;
    margin-left:1.5%;
}
#chat {
    float: left;
    width:28%;
    height: 400px;
    background-color:#22792d;
    margin-left:1.5%;
}
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LcfLy7za/

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda, mas o problema continua. Da forma que você sugeriu, se reduzir ou aumentar o tamanho do navegador, o layout ainda da uma dançada. Talvez tenha que mudar a estrutura toda, mas ainda não sei como.

Comment: @alexanderPataki eu respondi com código mas depois esqueci de colocar o código certo no jsFiddle... A versão com percentagens é assim: http://jsfiddle.net/LcfLy7za/2/